# Expanding an expression in a certain field

Tags: algebra-precalculus, field-theory

If $\mathbb F_2$ is a field of characteristic $2$, then we have $x+x=y+y=z+z=0$ for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb F_2$. When I expand $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$, I get
\begin{align}
(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) &= xz^2+y^2z+yz^2+x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+2xyz \\ 
&= xz^2+y^2z+yz^2+x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+(x+x)yz \\ 
&= xz^2+y^2z+yz^2+x^2y+x^2z+xy^2.
\end{align}
I got $2xyz=0$ in $\mathbb F_2$, but how can I simplify my above expression even more?

Comment: By $\Bbb F_2$ do you mean the field with two elements (as the notation suggests), or just some field of characteristic $2$ (as the phrasing of the first sentence suggests)?

Comment: Just some field of characteristic $2$. Maybe the notation $\mathbb F_2$ wasn't the correct notation.

Comment: Usually that notation is reserved for the field of two elements. NB Anurag A's answers seems to assume $\Bbb F_2$ is used in that more restrictive sense: Since $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible over the field $\Bbb F_2$ of two elements, $\Bbb F_2[x] / (x^2 + x + 1)$ is a field with $2^2 = 4$ elements, but in this field the image $\bar x$ of $x$ satisfies $\bar x^2 = \bar x + 1 \neq \bar x$.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{F}_2$, we also have $x^2=x$ and so on. So your expression will result in $0$. Another way to look at it is that at least two of $x,y$ or $z$ will take the same value, in which case at least one of $x+y, y+z, x+z$ will be $0$.

Comment: @Cookie since $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$, therefore if $x=0$, then $x^2=x$ and if $x=1$, then too $x^2=x$. Thus for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_2$, we have $x^2=x$.